# How to speed up excel file writing using Pythonwin32.com

Tags: python, numpy, win32com

I am reading data from an ascii file into an array and writing the data into an excel file for futher post processing . There are total of 337 columns and 1100 rows -- that makes 370700 cells in xlsx.

Writing the excel data file is taking very long time -- approximately 25-35 minutes on 16 GB machine.

Is there any other method to write data in excel file more efficiently ?

Any help would be appriciated.

```
import numpy as np 
import win32com.client as win32 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from win32com import client  from time
clock, time  start_time = clock()

itr = int(raw_input('Enter number of iteration = '))
f1 =open("Case_AT-6_WF_fl2.gid","r")

s2 = f1.read() 
a = s2.split() 

count=0 for col in open("Case_AT-6_WF_fl2.gid",'r'):
count = count+1 column = int(len(col.split()))
sm = int(itr * column)

digit = map(float,(a[(len(a)-sm):l
a[(column+7):(column*2+7)]

# preparing 2D matrix dig = np.array(digit)  dig1 =(dig.reshape

### *******Plotting
## print name

for i in range(len(name)):    
    print i,"=",name[i]

plot = int(raw_input("\nEnter variable number for plot =" ))

# writing Excel file*******************************************

print('file printing option: 1 = Yes 2= No') q = int(raw_input(
printing option = "))

if q==1 :
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    excel.Visible = False
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
    ws=wb.Sheets(1)
    ws.Name = "MyData"
    ws.Activate
    for kk in range(len(name)):
        ws.Cells(2,kk+1).Value = name[kk]
        ws.Cells(3,kk+1).Value = unit[kk]
m = 0
k =0
for j in range(itr):
    for k in range(column):
        ws.Cells(j+5,k+1).Value=dig1[j][k]
        m = m+1
       print '',m
print clock() - start_time, "seconds"

wb.SaveAs('C:\\Documents andSettings\\sd47086\\Desktop\\test\\MyWorkbook3.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: I think this belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why don't you something like openpyxl (http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/) or xlwt (http://www.python-excel.org/) ?

Answer (score 1):

It's usually much quicker to assign a Range than it is to set each cell individually.
You just have to make sure the python sequence matches the size of the range, eg
    ws.Range('A1:B10000').Value = ('a','b') * 10000